# awk repeat reading for all lines

Tags: awk

I am using the following line command which reads a file with 90289 columns and begins reading after 90307 lines but the results i am getting are only for the first line the 90307nth line. I want also to read the line 90308,90309...etc but skip only the first time the 90307 lines.

```
awk '{if (FNR==90307) for(i=2;i<=90289;i+=3) print x=$i,  y=$(i+1), z=$(i+2)}'
```

I need a script which

1.skips 90307 only one time
2.read the 90289 columns at EVERY line after the first 90307
3 repeat no 2 for all the lines

is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like you think you'll hit the 90307th line more than one time. Do you think that and, if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you have changed `==` to `>` yourself:

```
awk 'NR>90307{for(i=2;i<=90289;i+=3) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2) }'
```

I'm not sure why you are assigning to `x`,`y` and `z` either? Is your actual script larger and uses these values? Also do you actually want to be printing sets of 3 fields you don't mention this. You should edit your question with a clean description with a simple example and expected output.

Comment: I think the OP had hard-coded 90289 unnecessarily, NF should be fine since he says his input is `a file with 90289 columns`.

Comment: @EdMorton I scanned the question initially and thought the OP just wanted `>` instead of `==`. The more times I read it the more confused I get.